# Recursive CTE and SELECT

Tags: sql, recursion, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression

I have written a fairly simple recursive CTE statement.  The purpose is that it looks up a structure and returns the top level item

Here is the code

```
WITH cte_BOM(parent_serial_id, serial_id, serial_batch_no, sort)

AS (SELECT BOM.parent_serial_id, BOM.serial_id, p.serial_batch_no, 1
FROM serial_status AS BOM
INNER JOIN item_serial_nos p ON BOM.parent_serial_id = p.serial_id
WHERE BOM.serial_id = '16320' AND BOM.is_current = 'Y'

UNION ALL

SELECT
BOM1.parent_serial_id, bom1.serial_id, p1.serial_batch_no, cte_BOM.sort + 1
FROM cte_BOM
INNER JOIN serial_status AS BOM1 ON cte_BOM.parent_serial_id = 
BOM1.serial_id
INNER JOIN item_serial_nos p1 ON BOM1.parent_serial_id = p1.serial_id
WHERE BOM1.is_current = 'Y'
)

SELECT TOP 1
cte_BOM.*
FROM
cte_BOM
ORDER BY sort desc
```

As you can see I just hard code the `serial_id` at the moment.  What I now need to accomplish is to run this cte against a subset of data.  I’m now stuck on how I can do this.
So I would produce a list of serial_ids by means of another select statement, and then for each row use this `serial_id` in place of the ones that is currently hard coded and return the 1st record.  Importantly if a `serial_id` has no parent that should still return a row

The second `SELECT` would be this:

```
SELECT serial_id
FROM
item_serial_nos
WHERE
item_serial_nos.item_id = '15683'
```

Any suggestions appreciated. (using SQL 2008 R2)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your goal correctly, you can just remove the hardcoded `serial_id` from the cte and add the start `serial_id`:

```
WITH    cte_BOM(parent_serial_id, serial_id, serial_batch_no, sort, Original_Serial_id)
AS      (
            SELECT      BOM.parent_serial_id
            ,           BOM.serial_id
            ,           p.serial_batch_no
            ,           1
            ,           BOM.serial_id
            FROM        serial_status AS BOM
            INNER JOIN  item_serial_nos p 
                    ON  BOM.parent_serial_id = p.serial_id
            WHERE       BOM.is_current = 'Y'

            UNION ALL

            SELECT      BOM1.parent_serial_id
            ,           bom1.serial_id
            ,           p1.serial_batch_no
            ,           cte_BOM.sort + 1
            ,           cte_BOM.Original_Serial_id
            FROM        cte_BOM
            INNER JOIN  serial_status AS BOM1 
                    ON  cte_BOM.parent_serial_id = BOM1.serial_id
            INNER JOIN  item_serial_nos p1 
                    ON  BOM1.parent_serial_id = p1.serial_id
            WHERE       BOM1.is_current = 'Y'
)

SELECT      cte_BOM.*
FROM        cte_BOM
INNER JOIN  (
                SELECT      cte_BOM.Original_Serial_id
                ,           MAX(sort) sort_max
                FROM        cte_BOM
                WHERE       cte_BOM.Original_Serial_id IN (
                                                                SELECT  serial_id
                                                                FROM    item_serial_nos
                                                                WHERE   item_serial_nos.item_id = '15683'
                                                            )
                GROUP BY    cte_BOM.Original_Serial_id
            ) max_cte
        ON  max_cte.Original_Serial_id = cte_BOM.Original_Serial_id
        AND max_cte.sort_max = cte_BOM.sort
```

The recursive CTE is only executed when it's called from the last `select`, so it is only executed for those records that are selected in the `IN` query. So you shouldn't suffer a performance hit because of this.

Comment: Thanks, I think we're on the right track, except this bit:

     item_serial_nos.item_id = '15683'

Should return 400 rows, at the moment its just returning a single row?

Comment: Well, you are selecting `top 1`. I overlooked that, but you should change that if you have more than 1 `serial_id`.

Comment: I thought that was still needed because the top 1 ensure that the cte only returns the first result, If I take out it'll return all the previous levels.

Comment: That's correct if you only select one `serial_id`, if you want one record for each selected `serial_id` you have to find a different solution. I don't think you have access to `row_number` or `dense_rank` analytic functions, so you'll have to do it with a sub-query using `max()`. Edited answer to show how you can do that.

Comment: Hi, seems to be just the job, just undertaking some further testing.  Thanks.